# extract HoloLens 2 frame rate per second from Windows Device Portal

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, frame-rate, hololens

I need the frame rate data of HoloLens 2 while running an app. Is it possible to extract the fps data with the timestamp in a CSV file?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

I know I can monitor the fps from the device portal but I don't know how to extract it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no out-of-the-box function to get these data, but you can manually record them in the format you want, it should be noted that some calculations are required to get the current frame rate, you can refer to [DiagnosticsSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/diagnostics/diagnostics-system-getting-started?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) - [MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/MixedRealityToolkitVisualProfiler.cs at 265a0ea3621c84b88e4b02e7fcd1b5682afef56a · microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/265a0ea3621c84b88e4b02e7fcd1b5682afef56a/Assets/MRTK/Services/DiagnosticsSystem/MixedRealityToolkitVisualProfiler.cs#L326).